# Custom route handlers in ASP.Net WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm able to successfully register a custom route handler (deriving from IRouteHandler) inside global.asax.cs for a Web API route ala:

```
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{client}/api/1.0/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new{id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        ).RouteHandler = new SingleActionAPIRouteHandler();
```

However I can't seem to find a way to do this when trying to setup an in memory host for the API for integration testing, when I call HttpConfiguration.Routes.MapRoute I'm not able to set a handler on the returned IHttpRoute.

Should I be doing this differently (for instance by using a custom HttpControllerSelector)? I'd obviously like to do it the same way in both cases.

Thanks,
Matt

EDIT:

So what I ended up doing was basically following the advice from below, but simply overriding the HttpControllerDispatcher class as follows:

```
public class CustomHttpControllerDispatcher : HttpControllerDispatcher
{
    public CustomHttpControllerDispatcher(HttpConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
    {
    }
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // My stuff here

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are very right. Self host returns IHttpRoute and takes HttpMessageHandler as a parameter. There seems no inbuilt way to specificity a route handler.

**Update: To be a bit clearer**

You should almost certainly have a go at using a HttpControllerSelector and implementing a custom one... An example being. http://netmvc.blogspot.co.uk/

**What follows is a bit of experimentation** if the HttpControllerSelector is not sufficent for your requirements for what ever reason...

But, as you can see the `MapHttpRoute` does have an overload for `HttpMessageHandler` so you can experiment with this... [if the handler is NULL then it defaults to IHttpController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routing.ihttproute.handler%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) but you can implement your own and use this to direct to the correct controller... The MVC framework appears to use `[HttpControllerDispatcher]` [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f59892797e46#src/System.Web.Http/Dispatcher/HttpControllerDispatcher.cs), so borrowing some code you can place your own controller / route selection code here too - you have access to the route and selector and can swap it in and out yourself.

This CustomHttpControllerDispatcher code is for DEMO only... look for the line

> //DO SOMETHING CUSTOM HERE TO PICK YOUR CONTROLLER

And perhaps have a play with that...

**Example route:**

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: null,
            handler: new CustomHttpControllerDispatcher(config)
        );
```

**Example CustomHttpControllerDispatcher:**

```
public class CustomHttpControllerDispatcher : HttpMessageHandler
{
        private IHttpControllerSelector _controllerSelector;
        private readonly HttpConfiguration _configuration;

        public CustomHttpControllerDispatcher(HttpConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public HttpConfiguration Configuration
        {
            get { return _configuration; }
        }

        private IHttpControllerSelector ControllerSelector
        {
            get
            {
                if (_controllerSelector == null)
                {
                    _controllerSelector = _configuration.Services.GetHttpControllerSelector();
                }
                return _controllerSelector;
            }
        }

        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
                return SendAsyncInternal(request, cancellationToken);
        }

        private Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsyncInternal(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            IHttpRouteData routeData = request.GetRouteData();
            Contract.Assert(routeData != null);

            //DO SOMETHING CUSTOM HERE TO PICK YOUR CONTROLLER
            HttpControllerDescriptor httpControllerDescriptor = ControllerSelector.SelectController(request);
            IHttpController httpController = httpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(request);

            // Create context
            HttpControllerContext controllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(_configuration, routeData, request);
            controllerContext.Controller = httpController;
            controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor = httpControllerDescriptor;

            return httpController.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Mark,  I'll admit to being quite new to the internals of the WebAPI framework, could you explain why this approach is better than supplying a custom IHttpControllerSelector to the configuration?  It looks like the default HttpControllerDispatcher uses the ControllerSelector defined in the configuration to take care of the work that I'm looking to do.

Comment: @mattcole I should have been a bit clearer sorry - I wanted to confirm you are correct and that I suspect (as you already did) that you should have a look at a custom HttpControllerSelector http://netmvc.blogspot.co.uk/ as the preference if all you are doing is forwarding to a controller. I was only thinking that maybe you you were doing more than picking controllers and perhaps wanted to use other handlers other than controller etc... The CustomHttpControllerDispatcher idea was a bit of a plaything and experiment... sorry for not being clearer.

Comment: No problem Mark, in the end I went with a version of what you suggested, as I was effectively only changing some values in the routevalues I just overrode the SendAsync method, did my work and then let the pipeline continue on its way.

Comment: how to stop process and let it fall in secondaries? also i do namespace checking, if the 2 matching controller are exists that are in same list of namespaces, then its conflict, otherwise it's ok, and i only want to take the controller from that specific namespace