# Unit testing WebApi routes with custom handlers

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, routes

I'm having a problem testing routes and I think it's due to the route using a custom handler.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371269/custom-route-handlers-in-asp-net-webapi) points to a similar issue, but doesn't quite fix what I'm doing.

I have a `RouteConfiguration` class that simply houses the route definitions to enable me to pull them in for the application as well as any testing routines:

```
// the route
ApiRoutes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Custom",
    routeTemplate: "api/service/{service}/{method}/{arguments}",
    defaults: new { arguments = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: null,
    handler: new ServiceDispatcher(_httpConfiguration, _controllerHelper)
);
```

Now when trying to test this using a [similar pattern to this](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/testing-routes-in-asp-net-web-api/) way of mocking the route it doesn't find the route (404).  The select part looks like this (other code in [this article](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/testing-routes-in-asp-net-web-api/) is not shown):

```
HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost/api/service/foo/bar/foobar");
DefaultHttpControllerSelector controllerSelector = new DefaultHttpControllerSelector(configuration);
HttpControllerDescriptor descriptor = controllerSelector.SelectController(message);
```

My (educated?) guess is this `DefaultHttpControllerSelector` but I don't know how or if it can be changed to support what I'm doing.

So, can I make this current routine work using custom handlers or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Looking at your code, it appears you have not run the request through route matching...if you notice Filip's post, it has something called RouteTester and this does a call like `config.Routes.GetRouteData(request);`...this call kicks off the route matching logic...controller selector depends on the route data in the current request to select a controller and since there is not route data, you are seeing this behavior..

Comment: @KiranChalla I've actually got that part.  The 404 gets thrown when GetActionName() calls GetControllerType() which calls _controllerSelector.SelectController().  While I try and resolve this, I'll revert to testing the route is configured rather than actually testing the route through routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a MessageHandler attached to the route, the controller dispatcher is never even called.  It doesn't get that far.
If you want to test the routes, I would just call

```
    var routeDate = config.Routes.GetRouteData(request);
```

Then you can check the route values and test for the service, method and arguments parameters.

Comment: Brilliant, this was the knowledge I was missing.  I've simplified the test to simply work with the route data and got this working.  IHttpRouteData ShouldHave(this IHttpRouteData route, string key, object value) - thanks for your time.

Comment: @PhilCooper  Yes, it's not exactly obvious that the innocuous `GetRouteData` method actually does all the route matching and returns null if no route is found.